# Canonical way to use FutureBuilder with NetworkImage

Tags: flutter

I would like to be able to get to a network image within a single microtask if the image is already loaded. However, with the current API available in NetworkImage and FutureBuilder, this does not seem to be possible.

This is how we typically wire the two:

```dart
NetworkImage imageProvider = getSomeNetworkImage(id);
Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
imageProvider.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
    (ImageInfo info, _) => completer.complete(info.image));

return FutureBuilder<ui.Image>(
   future: completer.future,
   builder: (BuildContext futureBuilderContext, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
     if (!snapshot.hasData) {
       return _buildPlaceholder();
     } else {
       return _buildActual(context, snapshot.data, imageProvider);
     }
   },
);
```

addListener() immediately calls completer.complete() if the image is already there. However, FutureBuilder is based off of completer.future which does not complete until the next microtask. So even when the image is available, placeholder is displayed momentarily.

What is the best way to avoid this? Perhaps, imageProvider should expose a Future that prevents us from piping this through a completer?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a FutureBuilder, I would take advantage of the `syncCall` argument passed to the listener of the `ImageStream`. This will tell you if the image resolved immediately, meaning it is already cached. Otherwise you can call setState and trigger a rebuild when it does complete.

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key key, this.image, this.child}): super(key: key);

  final ImageProvider image;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State createState() => new ExampleState();
}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  bool _isImageLoaded = false;    

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.image
     .resolve(const ImageConfiguration)
     .addListener(_handleResolve);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // if syncCall = true, then _handleResolve will have already been called.
    if (_isImageLoaded)
      return new Image(widget.image);
    return widget.child;
  }

  void _handleResolve(ImageInfo info, bool syncCall) {
    _isImageLoaded = true;
    if (!syncCall) {
     // we didn't finished loading immediately, call setState to trigger frame
      setState(() { });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a decent solution, thanks Jonah. If not using FutureBuilder, there are several solution that exist. You can also set the image itself as part of the state and always call setState() from the listener (I like your solution better). I was hoping we can use FutureBuilder though since it provides a nice interface for async loading resources.

Comment: Realistically, there is almost no reason to ever use a FutureBuilder.  Correct use of one requires a StatefulWidget anyway, and at that point you might has well use a flag.